# REGEX: how to exclude filenames that include a dash/hyphen

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm going a little bit crazy to solve this problem.

I need to put a watermark with .htaccess to large image files on a website.
I found the php script, which works perfectly.

In .htaccess i added this rule:

`RewriteRule ^images/items/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ watermark.php?image=$1 [NC]`

Now I don't know how to filter jpg images, because the watermark must be added only to images without a dash "-" in the filename, because every item has different image sizes and I need to apply only to the big version (the one without the dash)

For example:

```
000001-m.jpg <- don't apply watermark here
000001-ms.jpg <- don't apply watermark here
000001-sm.jpg <- don't apply watermark here
000001.jpg <- this is the right file
```

I'm not so able with regex.. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

if this is a duplicate questions, mark it as duplicate, but let me know where I can find the solution! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[^-]` to match all characters except the dash:

```
RewriteRule ^images/items/([^-]*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ watermark.php?image=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like

```
RewriteRule ^images/items/([^-]+\.(gif|jpg|png))$ watermark.php?image=$1 [NC]
```

?